# css jquery checkbox toggle display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vb.net

I have this function to toggle the display of the text when clicked, but I have about 5 different of these in my application where everything is called different ID's, is there a way of doing that without having to create 5 different functions?

This is my attempt of doing it given the ID but am not sure on how to do without, but the issue i am getting when doing all is it will toggle all 5 at the same time, when its meant to be one by 1

```js
$('#isAgeSelected').click(function() {
    $("#txtAge").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="isAgeSelected"/>
<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">Age is something</div>
```

Or, is there a different way in doing it in vb.net?

All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `data-` attribute to the checkbox, containing the ID of the element you want toggled.

(Note that I changed the ID `isAgeSelected` to a class; IDs should always be unique, since JavaScript will only select the first instance of an ID that it finds.)

```js
$('.isAgeSelected').click(function() {
    $($(this).data('toggle')).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="#txtAge" class="isAgeSelected"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="#txtAge2" class="isAgeSelected"/>

<div id="txtAge" style="display:none">Age is something</div>
<div id="txtAge2" style="display:none">Age is nothing</div>
```

Comment: brilliant exactly what i wanted, but i am trying to use in an asp environment (ascx) user control but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, don't forget to accept your favorite answers to all your questions -- it encourages others to continue helping you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ID to select the checkboxes, use a generic class instead.

This solution relies on the fact that the text is the next sibling of the checkbox.

```js
$('.isAgeSelected').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle(this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="isAgeSelected"/>
<div class="txtAge" style="display:none">1Age is something</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="isAgeSelected"/>
<div class="txtAge" style="display:none">2Age is something</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="isAgeSelected"/>
<div class="txtAge" style="display:none">3Age is something</div>
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why it does not work in an asp environment? or of a different method to use in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Use a function. Like so:

```
function doSomething(firstObjectSelector, secondObjectSelector){
        $(firstObjectSelector).click(function() {
            $(secondObjectSelector).toggle(this.checked);
        });
}
```

Usage:

```
doSomething('#isAgeSelected', '#isAgeSelected'); //using ids
```

or

```
doSomething('.isAgeSelected', '.isAgeSelected'); //using classes
```

or

```
doSomething('div', 'span'); //using tags
```